# CURL and my little http client give different results

Tags: c, http, tcp

I have this little C program implementing a HTTP client. Basically I used [this reference code](https://github.com/langhai/http-client-c/blob/master/src/http-client-c.h) with slight modifications, mainly for debugging.

My problem is, that the content I get back using this is not quite the same as I get when I use `curl` for example.

Basically what the code does is:

- Construct a HTTP headers for a GET request
- Establishes TCP connection with the server
- Sends the HTTP headers
- Receives back a response

The read part looks like this:

```
while((recived_len = recv(sock, BUF, BUFSIZ-1, 0)) > 0)
    {   
        BUF[recived_len] = '\0';
        response = (char*)realloc(response, strlen(response) + strlen(BUF) + 1);
        sprintf(response, "%s%s", response, BUF);
        
    }
```

In particular, I always get in the begining of the body part 4 bytes which I don't understand where they come from:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 20 Apr 2021 09:17:54 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: 1P_JAR=2021-04-20-09; expires=Thu, 20-May-2021 09:17:54 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; Secure
Set-Cookie: NID=213=ts4T4alAR2ODEf4vlWrmoZj-cjJcAXACbbxf64Zte4lEbuvUgik6TUgKkdY5OVHDQuTWM59DekV3ayNXDl08TcETU-WwztPVmMFz9BXegk93QFyno5WCS9fJDGq3sSrbFsFjxPOPCLTOx-b8H3a4Ed_HbI9lXBocjGu07ULo8PY; expires=Wed, 20-Oct-2021 09:17:54 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
Accept-Ranges: none
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

5225 // what is this?
<!doctype html><html dir="rtl" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="iw"><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"><meta content="/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" itemprop="image"><title>Google</title><script nonce="ks4dIW3TspucDhFX4XRWZA==">(function(){window.google={kEI:'Qpx-YKSmGIeSaPf3mJgP',
```

The headers part looks fine, so I don't think it's a problem with the resquet's headers, and also the beggining of the content (except from these 4 bytes) looks fine. However, down the stream things get messier and it gets quite different from the `curl` response, which seems much more reasonable.

Can someone tell me why this happening?

If I try to send a GET request to

### EDIT

OK thanks I understand this 4 bytes are the length of the Chunk, since the Transfer-Encoding is of type `chunk`. From what I've read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding) about it, chunks should be sent one after another, with each one preceded by (or followed by, depending from where you look) `\r\n<chunk_length>\r\n`

Basically what I'm trying to do is implement a MP3 player, so I want to be able to read a stream of MP3 from a streaming server and play it.

When I use `curl` to get the stream, I can play it. I can even see that the data is sent in chunks as described above.

However, when I use my program, the data I'm getting is for some reason not structured properly..

My final goal in all this is to use ESP8266 module as a Radio player. I try to understand all the moving parts that should be involved in order to make this work. First I want to implement this on my PC before I move to working on the ESP8266

### EDIT #2

Thanks to @Emanuel P I noticed that I get back from the server content type of `text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1`, so I added a `Content-Type: */*` just as `curl` does, and I do get back a `Content-Type: audio/mpeg`, as expected, but it still doesn't work for some reason - the MP3 player doesn't read the file well:

```
$ ./mp3player.out stream.mp3 
Note: Illegal Audio-MPEG-Header 0x04e248be at offset 2258.
Note: Trying to resync...
Note: Skipped 87 bytes in input.

Warning: Big change from first (MPEG version, layer, rate). Frankenstein stream?
```

Comment: `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` is the short answer. This is why we use HTTP libraries, because HTTP servers tend to support multiple encodings, compression algorithms etcetera. Do you really want to implement all of those yourself?

Comment: Those are the number of bytes that follow in the next `chunk`. This is actually the easiest of the various Transfer-Encodings of HTTP to implement yourself. It can be a nice exercise to implement it, but for a release project you'll probably want a library handling the encodings.

Comment: `charset=ISO-8859-1` That might also give you a hint. Servers sometimes choose a different charset depending on the request, in an attempt to be compatible with old web clients. You may be expecting UTF-8, but this isn't. Good luck on your project.

Comment: Thanks ! I added a `Accept: */*` header, just as `curl` does, and I do get back a `Content-Type: audio/mpeg`, as expected., but still doesn't work :(

Comment: Capture the contents in files and compare them.